# Why is tcrossprod() faster than %*% for matrix multiplication?

Tags: r, matrix

I've been some matrix multiplies on large matrices.  I noticed that if I have two matrices, `m1` and `m2`, if I first set `m3 <- t(m2)`, then doing `tcrossprod(m1, m3)` is faster than `m1 %*% m2`.  Why is that?

**Example**

```
set.seed(2017)
m1 <- matrix(runif(n=100000), nrow=10000, ncol=10000)
m2 <- matrix(runif(n=50000), nrow=10000, ncol=5)
m3 <- t(m2)

# check for equality
all.equal(m1 %*% m2, tcrossprod(m1, m3))

# timings
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  m1 %*% m2, 
  tcrossprod(m1, m3)
)

Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 mult1(m1, m2) 438.9080 458.5851 480.7021 479.6811 494.1340 644.6663   100   b
 mult2(m1, m3) 370.4765 391.8060 406.1318 403.1972 416.1648 591.8057   100  a
```

Unfortunately this example isn't as egregious as some of the others I came across, but I think it still illustrates the point.

Comment: At a quick glance, it appears that both are implemented via C code in `do_matprod`, but with different options. Right off the bat, the `%*%` does a very small amount of extra work checking if the arguments are S4 objects. I doubt that takes much time, but there are probably other differences if you wade through `do_matprod`.

Comment: ...additionally, it looks like when it comes time to actually do the matrix multiple, the `tcrossprod` case has some alternate pathways for the symmetric case, and generally use different C functions for the multiply. Probably someone more up on all the various matrix multiply algorithm implementations would be able to explain why some instances allow for shortcuts and hence some speed ups.

Comment: @joran Thanks. I figured `tcrossprod()` might be testing properties of the matrices before picking the best multiplication algorithm.  Wish I had a better example that shows the larger speed difference I was experiencing.  If I run into it again, I'll update my post.

Comment: Sorry I don't know more about the technical details, but then again you can purchase some pretty weighty textbooks on this topic and probably get whole graduate degrees on it, so the specific reasons in a particular case might be pretty esoteric.